Is it possible to work with Material-UI DatePicker in "pure date format"?
My question intentionally is "Is it possible?" and not "How to?", because I am not sure whether it is possible at all. Material UI X DatePicker API shows that DatePicker value type is object - apparently it is standard JS/DT Date, which has always are time component as well and you can not just strip time from it.
But sometimes it is very important to have date only - e.g. the John Brown may start work on 10.04.2024 in FR TZ and this 10.04.2024 should be displayed in React web app (with DatePicker) as 10.04.2024 in any TZ, any browser. But, if Date object is used, then it may be possible that from the US-located computers DatePicker sees the browser TZ and displays 10.04.2024 FR as 09.04.2024 that is quite confusing, as clients know that John Brown works in FR branch and all the legal data about him should be displayed keeping in mind that they refer to the FR legal system.
So - maybe there is pure date option for DatePicker where can I pass just date string DD-MM-YYYY and the DatePicker displays this date exactly as such without assuming that it is DD-MM-YYYY-UTC-MIDNIGHT. Date object always have time. strings may go with just date data?

Check this https://mui.com/x/react-date-pickers/timezone/

Indeed, 'timezone' attribute would solve the issue. But I have tried and failed https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78956692/how-to-set-custom-timezone-for-the-material-ui-x-datepicker

OK - I managed to solve the issue by combining datejs adapter for DatePicker and with timezone attribute. More on the final solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78956692/how-to-set-custom-timezone-for-the-material-ui-x-datepicker/78957176#78957176 timezone attribute (at least with dayjs) is very handy - it determines both the presentation and what value is pased to the onChange handler.
