How to set custom timezone for the Material UI X DatePicker?
I am using Material UI X DatePicker, whose API https://mui.com/x/react-date-pickers/timezone/ includes timezone attribute. I am trying to test it. I know that 13.04.2024 00:00:00 in the Helsinki may be represented as '2024-04-12T21:00:00.000Z'. My Windows 10 computer has '(UTC+01:00) Brussels, Copenhagen, Madrid, Paris', but I am asking my DatePicker to show this timestamp in the Europe/Helsinki timezone.
So, for the React code
   const handleDateChange = useCallback((value, context, fieldName) => {

    alert(value);

    setEmployeeFieldValue({ 
      name: fieldName, 
      value: value,
      componentKey: componentKey,
    });
  }, [setEmployeeFieldValue]);

return ( ...
  <DatePicker
    label="Birthday"
    value={new Date('2024-04-12T21:00:00.000Z')}
    name="birthday"
    onChange={(newValue, context) => handleDateChange(newValue, context, 'birthday')}
    timezone="Europe/Helsinki"
    slotProps={{ textField: { 
    variant: "standard",
    fullWidth: true,
       } }}
    /> ...)

I expect 2 things:

That 13.04.2024 (midnight in Helsinki) should be displayed, but - instead - DatePicker displays 12.04.2024.
That setting date to 14.04.2024 will display something like '2024-04-13T21:00:00.000Z' (which is UTC that corresponds to the Helsinki 14.04.2024 midnight), because: 1) it can be reasonably assumed that DatePicker will put time to midnight; 2) I indicated Helsinki timezone in the attribute. But, instead the alert shows Sun Apr 14 2024 23:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)

So - essentially - it seems to me that DatePicker ignores timezone attribute? Both - for displaying value and for updating value.

I used MUI Date Pickers in lots of cases and i faced a case like this but i didnt solve it like you, I added the timezone to the date itself. As I understand the date picker will select just the date and it'll ignore the time.
to solve this issue you can add the minuits and seconds to the date and save it. and when you use the function you can use moment.utc(date).local().format(). If that what are you looking for i can help you.

Thx, but timezone attribute solved it. Is feature in development and might not be available at Time at your projects.

I figured it out - I had to used dayjs adapter as was stated in https://mui.com/x/react-date-pickers/timezone/:

UTC and timezones support is an ongoing effort.
Only AdapterDayjs, AdapterLuxon and AdapterMoment are currently
compatible with UTC dates and timezones.

I did use DateFns and exactly that adapter was not supported. I had to wrap DatePicker with:
<LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs} adapterLocale={fi}>

And use datejs object in the value:
value={datejs('2024-04-12T21:00:00.000Z')}

